# Dynamically add key value map to struct

Tags: dictionary, go, prometheus

I am trying to figure out how I can add the key value pairs of a `map[string]string` into my prometheus.Labels struct.

If you've got experience with prometheus: I am trying to dynamically add labels and it's values.

```
labelsMap := make(map[string]string)
labelsMap["nodepool"] = "default"
labelsMap["zone"] = "europe-west"

// here I'd like to add my key / value pairs from my map
containerLabels := prometheus.Labels{
    "node":      "nodename",
    "container": "foo",
    "qos":       "bar",
}
requestedContainerCPUCoresGauge.With(containerLabels).Set(containerMetric.RequestedCPUCores)
```

**My question:**

How can I dynamically add the key/value pairs from my given map `labelsMap` in my containerLabels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simple `for range` loop on `labelsMap`, and add each pair, e.g.:

```
containerLabels := prometheus.Labels{}
for k, v := range labelsMap {
    containerLabels[k] = v
}
```

Or since [`prometheus.Labels`](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#Labels) is just a simple map:

```
type Labels map[string]string
```

And if you don't want to modify the `labelsMap` afterwards, a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) also works:

```
containerLabels := prometheus.Labels(labelsMap)
```